# Openssl 1.1.1 library gives an error on selfsigned signatures

Tags: c, openssl

As development team we try to upgrade the openssl libraries in our product. Unfortunately we are stuck with a problem when linking agains openssl 1.1.1. The error we phase is
verify_callback: [-10] Could not complete SSL handshake: Certificate error: General verification, self signed certificate [18]

As if we cannot use the self signed certificates anymore. In our code we access the google mail server using a TLS connection. This was working fine with the older version of openssl.

My question:
Is there a way to get around this error? Are there build options to get a library which is compatible with older Openssl libs?

Help is very much appreciated
Jasper de Keijzer

Answer (score 0):

After studying the new API of OpenSSL I found out that you can define the maximum protocol to be used. In case of self-signed certificates I use now

SSL_set_max_proto_version(ssl, TLS1_2_VERSION);

This solves the handshake error which I got when using the default TLS setting. This happens to be TLS1.3.